# Saving a rs232 message to a variable

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, uart

If I receive a message via RS232 consisting of 2 Byte length, e.g. 0000 0001 0001 1100 (that is 100011100, lsb on the right), I wanna save it to a variable called value.

I am "decoding" the byte stream with this step:

rxByte = Serial1.read()

`messageContent[0] = rxByte`

`messageContent[1] = rxByte`

with the first rxByte having the value 0000 0001 and the second 0001 1100.
Or are those values already converted internally to HEX or DEC?

Now I have seen code that saves it this way to value:

`uint32_t value = messageContent[0] *256 + messageContent[0]`

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`messageContent[0] *256` is essentially a bitshift: the code is equivelent to (and more readable as)

```
uint32_t value = (messageContext[0]) << 8 + messageContent[1];
```

So if `messageContent[0] = 0x01' and messageContext[2] = 0x1C

```
value = (0x01 << 8)+0x1C
value = (0x0100)+0x1C
value = 0x011C
```

Works find, but depending on the endianess of your machine, it is equivalent to:

```
 uint32_t value = *((uint16_t*)(messageContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

Decoding procedure:

```
//char messageContent[2]; //Always keep in mind datatypes in use!!!
messageContent[0] = Serial1.read()
messageContent[1] = Serial1.read()
```

Way you were doing was placing same value in both positions.

If you want to read both bytes into a 16-bit or bigger integer:

```
short int messageContent = Serial1.read()<<8+Serial.read();
```

> Or are those values already converted internally to HEX or DEC?

Data is always binary. Hex or Dec is just its representation. You say "variable x as a value of 123" - this is a human interpretation, actually variable x is a block of memory comprised of some bytes which are by themselves groups of 8 bits.

> Now I have seen code that saves it this way to value:
>
> uint32_t value = messageContent[0] *256 + messageContent[0]

That's like I tell you `45` `thousands` and `123`, so you build your number as `45*1000+123=45123`. 256 is 2^8, equal to a full byte, b'1 0000 0000'.

Comment: " you build your number as 45*1000+123=45123 " I understood the why, but not the how... So the computer always knows, that "*256" is decimal? it could also be hex and then the bitshift would not work.

To your first point: of course the rxbyte=Serial1.read() is made every iteration, it was just for showing how I do it.

Comment: C compiler rules define what's written (in your source C code) as decimal (255), hex (0xff) or octal (0377).